# Workday: API to get single worker based on email address

Tags: workday-api

In [Workday](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v31.1/Human_Resources.html), Is there any API to get worker details based on email address

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible through the Public APIs.

Your Workday team or Integration Administrator could set up a custom report enabled for REST calls with email address as the prompt, though. The Workers from Prompt data source is good for this.